# Using $this when not in object context in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I know this question already has answers but I did not understand so asked again **So please help.**

What does this error actually mean ?

> Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in
>   C:\wamp\www\provisioning\application\controllers\customer\provisioning.php
>   on line 27

```
public function index(){
  $users = $this->data['tenant_users'] = $this->customer_user_m->tenant_users();
  $domain = $users[0]['domain'];
  $site = $users[0]['site_key'];
  $tenant_id = $users[0]['tenant_id'];
  $site = $this->session->userdata('site');
  $user_table = $this->session->userdata('user_table');

  function getOTAURLExt($ext){
    var_dump($this);
  }

  function getOTAURLSite(){
    echo "Site executed";
  }

  $this->db->select('*');
  $this->db->where('id', $tenant_id);
  $this->db->from('tenant');
  $query = $this->db->get();
  $result = $query->result_array();

  if(empty($this->input->post('md'))){
    $URL = getOTAURLSite($site);
  }else{

    $username = $result[0]['username'];

    $table_user = $username . "_users";


    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->where($table_user . '.site_key', $site);
    $this->db->join('mlcsites', 'mlcsites.site_key =' . $table_user . '.site_key');
    $this->db->from($table_user);
    $query_table = $this->db->get();
    $information = $query_table->result_array();


    $ext = $information[0]['ext'];


    $count = count($information);
    $found = false;
    for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++){
      $domain = $information[$i]['domain'];
      $ext = $information[$i]['ext'];

      $hash = do_hash($ext . "@" . $domain, 'md5');

      if($hash == $this->input->post('md')){

        $found = true;
        break;
      }
    }

    if($found == true){
      $URL = getOTAURLExt($ext);
    }
  }
  if(empty($URL)){

  }

  $this->data['subview'] = 'provisioning/index';
  $this->load->view('_layout_main', $this->data);
}
```

What could be the possible solution to this?

Comment: what's that line for ` $users = $this->data['tenant_users'] =$this->customer_user_m->tenant_users();` multi assign !!

Comment: code for line 27 in provisioning.php?

Comment: @DavidJawphan ignore it , It should be like this $this->data['tenant_users'] =$this->customer_user_m->tenant_users();` so i will pass tenant_users array to view

Comment: @itzmukeshy7 i am getting error when i use  echo $this->session->userdata('site_key');

Comment: @itzmukeshy7 its not allowing me to use $this

Comment: what is the datatype of `$this->session->userdata` ?

Comment: try printing `$this` before this line and share output;

Comment: @kiro112 its just codeigniter way to access the session variable

Comment: @itzmukeshy7 it shows nothing

Comment: May you share all code of this file may be on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/)

Comment: Load first the `$this->load->library('session');` before call $this->session (in your __construct() function for example).

Comment: So the problem is the function `getOTAURLExt`? Where and how are you *calling* that function?

Comment: @deceze in the function getITAURLExt i want to perform some database transaction using active records

Comment: @itzmukeshy7 i have posted the whole code here

Comment: @JP.Aulet i have already loaded it in my base controller

Comment: @deceze yes my problem is that function

Comment: You can't access `$this` in that function because of function scope you wrapped this function in a function `index()` move it outside `index()`; then access `$this->getOTAURLExt()`;

Comment: Okay I will try that

Comment: @itzmukeshy7 if i try to move it outside index function it show error  Call to undefined function getOTAURLExt()

Comment: call like this `$this->getOTAURLExt()`;

Comment: thanks @itzmukeshy7 it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the code that you provided, there seems to be nothing on "line 27" so IMHO it seems to be caused on "line 10"

```
function getOTAURLExt($ext){
    var_dump($this); // <<< This seems to be causing error.
}
```

Now If you need the variable `$this` inside the function you could either

1. Pass it as an Argument (If you only need to read values from the object).
2. Pass it by Reference (If you need to update the object.).
3. Declare it Global.

...then use it inside the function.

Comment: you are right in that function i am trying to echo $this->session->userdata('site'); so i get that error